# Using static libraby in MFC

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mfc, linker, static-libraries

I try to use a static library in my MFC project but I get the following linker error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Csetkliens, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2012.05.20. 16:12:49.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Csetkliens.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in Csetkliens.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Csetkliens.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Csetkliens.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) already defined in Csetkliens.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgrptw.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in libcmtd.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in libcmtd.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgrealloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in libcmtd.lib(fflush.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in libcmtd.lib(_file.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgfree.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _floor already defined in libcmtd.lib(_floor_pentium4_.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _ldexp already defined in libcmtd.lib(_ldexp_.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _abort already defined in libcmtd.lib(abort.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isspace already defined in libcmtd.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>D:\Projektek\V.felev\Felulettervezes (MFC) - Halozatok\Csetkliens\Debug\Csetkliens.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.29
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The name of the static library is kriptolib.lib it is my own product. It doesn't use any MFC. I can't figure out what is the problem.

The problem occurs when I try to make a new object from the kriptolib.

```
theApp.encryption = new RC4();
```

If I comment the line below the compiler doesn't show any errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve the following linker errors in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925540/how-to-resolve-the-following-linker-errors-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need change the testing project to use MTd（Multi-threaded Debug）.

From the Property Pages select Configuration Properties ==> C/C++ ==> Code Generation ==> Runtime Library ==> Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).