# Using SystemC in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, systemc

I am new to SystemC and I just compiled it for using it with VS2010 using [this](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IL2452/Sept2009/TUTORIAL-SystemC-with-Microsoft-Visual-Studio.pdf) tutorial. But when I tried to debug the following program:

```
#include <systemc.h>

SC_MODULE (systemcTest) {
SC_CTOR (systemcTest) {

}
void say_hello() {
    cout << "Hello World.\n";
}
};
int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
systemcTest hello("HELLO");
hello.say_hello();
return(0);
}
```

I got 51 errors similar to the following error:

```
error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in SystemC.lib(sc_simcontext.obj) \msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
```

Most were related to msvcprtd.lib, libcmtd.lib. 
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly related to the different MS runtime libraries used for project used for compiling the SystemC library (SystemC.lib) and your SystemC project. With MS compiler, there are 4 different runtime libraries:

- Multithreaded (/MT) --> LIBCMT.lib
- Multithreaded-Debug (/MTd) --> LIBCMTD.lib
- Multithreaded-DLL (/MD) --> MSVCRT.lib,MSVCPRT.lib + MSVCR100.DLL,MSVCP100.DLL
- Multithreaded-Debug-DLL (/MDd) --> MSVCRTD.lib,MSVCPRTD.lib + MSVCR100D.DLL,MSVCP100D.DLL

It seems that you used /MDd to compile your SystemC.lib, but you are using /MTd to compile your SystemC project. You can correct it:

From the Property Pages select Configuration Properties ==> C/C++ ==> Code Generation ==> Runtime Library ==> Multithreaded-Debug-DLL (/MDd).

A similar thread can be found here: [Linker errors between multiple projects in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604484/linker-errors-between-multiple-projects-in-visual-c)